# Reference to nextElementSibling undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm building a product slider that updates its state every time after you have swiped. To find the references to the previous and next elements in the slide I'm using the nextElementSibling/previousElementSibling. This works fine in Chrome on desktop, even if the slides are loaded in dynamically using Ajax.

However, on mobile Safari and Chrome I get the following error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'currentProduct.dataset')
```

It seems like once I reach the elements in the slide that have been loaded using ajax do not have the nextElementSibling/previousElementSibling references anymore.

```
updateState: function (direction, xOffset, outerOffset) {

        // Old current product
        var currentProduct = this.state.currentProduct;

        // Set new current product
        if (direction === 'next') {
            currentProduct = this.state.currentProduct.nextElementSibling;
        } else if (direction === 'prev') {
            currentProduct = this.state.currentProduct.previousElementSibling;
        }

        // Set new state
        this.state.currentProduct = currentProduct;
        this.state.prevProductUrl = currentProduct.dataset.prev;
        this.state.nextProductUrl = currentProduct.dataset.next;

        // Load new sibling
        if (currentProduct.nextElementSibling === null) {

            $.get(this.state.nextProductUrl).done( function(data) {
                // Insert next product
                this.insertProduct(data, 'next');

                this.setContainerSize(this.productContainer.children.length);
            }.bind(this));

        } else if (currentProduct.previousElementSibling === null) {

            $.get(this.state.prevProductUrl).done( function(data) {
                // Insert next product
                this.insertProduct(data, 'prev');

                this.setContainerSize(this.productContainer.children.length, true);
            }.bind(this));
        }

        // Set new xOffset
        this.state.xOffset = xOffset;

        // Update offset of container element
        this.state.outerOffset = outerOffset;
    }
```

Using the .next()/.prev() functions of jQuery doesn't help either and gives the same results.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: With that error message I would check the value you assign to `currentProduct`. I suspect it is `null`. Just add a `console.log (currentProduct);` after you set its value and check on the debug console.

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed `null`, that's because the value of `this.state.currentProduct.nextElementSibling` is `null` when the elements are loaded with ajax. The strange thing is that this only happens in mobile Chrome and Safari. Desktop Chrome doesn't return `null` but the actual next/previous element.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.. The ajax request wasn't working due to working with a proxy.. Oops.